# How to use hook_for :devise_install in my gem generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, hook, generator

I'm trying to install Devise when I run the InstallGenerator of my gem.

This is what I did so for:

```
module Baco
  module Generators
    class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base

      hook_for :devise_install

    end
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work, and I really don't know how I should get it to work..

I tried to search for it but the documentation didn't help me out, and I can't find any tutorials. I've only seen that hook_for is used to use generators in generators.

Maybe I'm not in the right direction at all, if so, please point me in the right direction..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching I came across a gem called "ActiveAdmin", which does exactly what I want. After some digging in their source, I found that what I need isn't `hook_for`, but `invoke`..

This is what is working for my problem:

```
def install_devise

  require 'devise'

  if File.exists?(File.join(destination_root, "config", "initializers", "devise.rb"))
    log :generate, "No need to install devise, already done."
  else
    log :generate, "devise:install"
    invoke "devise:install"
  end

end
```